# MVC .NET Refresh (Update) PartialView witout AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a page with partial view that contains DevEx ComboBox with Add button and DevEx GridView ( I omitted GridView code). Page is showing properly with that partial view, only I have a problem with refreshing it.

```
//_ProductAppsGridViewPartial
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Apps</h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AppsGridViewPartialAddNew", "Products", new { ProductID = ViewBag.ProductID }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            <h5>Add new App:</h5>
        @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(settings =>
        {
            //..do some settings for ComboBox - some code omitted
            settings.Properties.ValueField = "ApplicationID";
            settings.Properties.TextField = "Name";
        }).BindList(Model.AppsNotInProduct).GetHtml()
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I have action on my controller that adds selected app in database and returns a PartialView with the same (but refreshed) model, but response shows only that partial View. Here is a part of Controller's action that returns PartialView after updating database:

```
public ActionResult ProductAppsGridViewPartialAddNew(int ProductID)
        {    
            //....update DB code - WORKS FINE
            ..
            var model = GetProductAppsPartialModel(ProductID);
            ViewBag.ProductID = ProductID;
            ViewBag.CanEdit = true;
            return PartialView("_ProductAppsGridViewPartial", model);
        }
```

Is it possible to refresh a partial view wihout AJAX, maybe something i wrote above? So the main problem here is that i get new page showing only a partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh part of a page you will need to use ajax to replace only the needed content. You will also need to use JavaScript to re-render the HTML contained in the partial. MVC comes with some ajax helpers or you can do it yourself with jquery. At the moment the action result is returning the partial as requested but the browser is being told it is receiving a whole new page and is displaying as such.

Adding this [link to Microsoft ajax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533(v=vs.100).aspx) to show some of your options.

I would use jquery and do this yourself. Also try to remember that mvc is a server side framework to help you return http messages to the browser. You are trying to manipulate things client side. Live client side updates always need ajax to get data. Replacing items in the DOM needs some form of JavaScript. Libraries like jquery make this a lot easier. Have a look at jquery ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks @Luthervd. So there is no way to refresh partially without ajax and JS? I thought that MVC is smart enough to refresh a region of partial view if I return a partial view :). I am new to MVC so I apologize for possibly stupid questions.

Comment: Look at my revised answer

Comment: Thank you! I got it working! Now i have another problem, but it is a problem with DevEx: ComboBox and Grid are part of partial view, when I add something from CB, after refresh it is in Grid and not in CB anymore, which is fine. But when I call Delete link in DevEx Grid, it accepts a partial view and shows it in alert dialog. I suppose that Grid expects pure Grid HTML for its actions... I tried to get CB and Grid in sync with generating one partial view, but no luck...

Comment: Ok glad its working. Your asking a separate question now so ask it in another thread so the answers don't get confused. Feel free to mark this as be right answer if it helped you solve your issue.

Comment: I got that working too (it was specific because of using DevExpress UI extensions). Maybe I should make another thread and post my solution?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it as I assume  the info can be found on devexpress makers help files or website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this code.
Note here we need to keep ajax call for update the partial view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", new { model = @Model.ID },
new AjaxOptions
{
OnSuccess = "onSuccessRefresh "
}))
{
<table>
<td>
</td>
<td>    <input type="button" value="AddValue" /> </td>
</table>
}
```

Handle the code onsuccess event using jquery:-

```
function onSuccessRefresh {
// refersh your page or table
}
```

This is not the full code. but I think it will help to you